# how to remote sound from imac to iphone 5 via bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, imac

I was wondering, how can I remote sound from my imac 2010 to iphone 5 via bluetooth? I've been trying to google it but seems like my searching input isn't right or something I don't know.

I want to be able to listen to anything on my Imac to my Iphone via bluetooth.

Please guys help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone guys? plez help if any solution!

Answer (score 0):

AIRFOIL and AIRFOIL speaker is the answer. I have found it. It works great. I can listen whatever audio from my imac to iphone and the other way around from Iphone to Imac. Perfect!!!